# File missing error iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I have a sample project with multiple schemes.I am new to such a project.

I want to know **How When** and **Where** do we use such a flow(multiple projects in a single project).

See the image below,***I am getting a file missing error*** while I try to build the project.But I don't know why I am getting such an error.The file that says is missing is already there in the project folder.

What am i doing wrong?I have added the three schemes by directly clicking **+addfiles** button to "my project " button at the bottom of the navigation pane.

[image]

***the error is : "HTTPConnection.h file is missing."***

[image]

Comment: Post the complete error message.

Comment: Where and when does the error appear: at the point of the #import, while you're compiling...?

Comment: see the updated question.I think i am getting this error at the point of import.

Comment: In your build settings for DRM_test, check that the location of HTTPConnection.h is included in your Header Search Paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question....

Sub-projects inside a project are useful if they build something (a library, usually) that your main project depends on.  If the library is under development at the same time as the application, you may want to build it from source as a dependency rather than pre-building it and managing the installation of it as a binary file.

As for the missing file problem, including it in the project (or sub-project) doesn't automatically make it visible if it's not also in the source directory.  In that case, it needs to be added to the project's header search paths.

Comment: It also means if the sub-project is a library it gets built for the right CPU architecture and platform (Simulator, iOS, or OSX).

Comment: Header search path is empty.How do I add the path?what about user search path?how are they both different?

Comment: /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/DRM_test/CocoaHTTPServer-master/Core/HTTPConnection.h ....this is the complete path of the missing file.how to add this?

Comment: The easy way is: open a Finder window showing the directory the file is in, double click on the value of the Header Search Path field in Xcode so that it opens a list box of paths, drag the folder icon into the list box.